# (Sencha Touch 2.2.1) Error occurred when generate build native with Sencha CMD

Tags: cmd, sencha-touch, touch, sencha-touch-2.2

Good Day, was generating my application with Sencha CMD and the following error occurred when trying to generate a native build with Sencha CMD (image below)

[image: Error]

Thanks

Comment: This might be valid for your case http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?259808-3.1.0.256-Error-Package-name-contains-invalid-character